# Select Next or previous row on unordered set of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a UNION SQL query that generate unordered set of rows.  The result is same with

```
+----+----------------------+-------+
| id | name                 | value |
+----+----------------------+-------+
| 3  | John                 | 21    |
+----+----------------------+-------+
| 2  | Jim                  | 5     |
+----+----------------------+-------+
| 4  | Adrian               | 25    |
+----+----------------------+-------+
| 1  | Sam                  | 22    |
+----+----------------------+-------+
```

If the second row is selected, How to I can select next or previous row?

Comment: Could you post your query..

Comment: Query: (Select id, name, value from buyers order by id)  union (select id, name, value from seller order by id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common trick for missing `rownum` function in MySql:

```
SELECT
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, 
    id, name, value
FROM
    (
        (SELECT id, name, value FROM buyers ORDER BY id) 
        UNION
        (SELECT id, name, value FROM seller ORDER BY id) 
    ) subq,
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
```

Then use the `rownum` field to navigate between rows.